# Delphi Sharesheet on iOS7

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe4, delphi-xe6

I have tested underneath on both Delphi XE4, XE5 and XE6:

When using this official iOS sharesheet demo code [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE4/iOSCodeSnippets/iOS%20ShareSheet/uMain.pas#l33%20here)

Looking like this:

```
procedure TShareSheetForm.ShowShareSheetAction1BeforeExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
ShowShareSheetAction1.Bitmap.Assign(imgCameraPicture.Bitmap);
end;

procedure TShareSheetForm.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
begin
imgCameraPicture.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
end;
```

Or closer to what actually happens:

```
TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXShareSheetActionsService, IInterface(FSharingService));
FSharingService.Share(btnSocialPicShare, '...', imgSocialPic.Bitmap);
```

will only show Twitter - at least when testing on iOS7

After searching Google, it seems both Instagram and Facebook (now) require special handling:

e.g. Instagram:
https://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/#

e.g. Facebook
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share

Has any gotten image sharing workng with Facebook / Instagram etc. in iOS7 using Delphi?

Comment: AFAIK XE4 does not support iOS7. http://members.adug.org.au/2013/09/18/dont-be-a-bloody-idiot/

Comment: iOS7 UI is not supported, but I have debugging and everything working. Check e.g. http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/10/making-delphi-xe-4-debug-for-ios-devices-with-xcode-5/